# Localization of Default.png is not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, default

I wonder if anyone has encountered the same problem and how they solve it.

I want to localize Default.png so I do the following steps which from what I understand should be the correct way (please correct me if  I'm wrong).

1. Select Default.png in xcode
2. Command-I to Get Info
3. Click on Make File Localizable
4. Go back to General Tab (why Apple, why?)
5. Click on Add Localization
6. Enter es for Spanish according to this:
7. In finder I replace the Default.png in the es.lproj folder

I have tried in both the simulator and on an iPhone with changing the language between English and Spanish, but I only get the original file. Other localizations like app name and strings works just fine, but not this one...

I'm on xcode 3.2.3

Thanks

Comment: What is the size of your launch image? In Finder, can you see Default.png in each .lproj folder?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the targets? Deleting the app and reinstalling?

Comment: Hi Guys. The size is 78k for both versions. I can see the Default.png in both English.lproj and es.lproj folders (and yes they are different ;-).  Have tried cleaning, cleaning targets, deleted app in both simulator and physical device but no difference  :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this solution from Developers Forum (credit to Sascha Paulus, thanks Sascha!).

I had a similar problem in another project with localization, but the solution worked for both issues.

Here we go:

1. Delete App from Simulator (just to be sure)
2. Delete all versions of the localized Default.png (in XCode & on Disc)
3. Select Build > Clean All Targets
4. If not done yet, make the Localizion Directories (e.g. es.lproj, de.lproj)
5. Copy the localized Default.png in the appropriate Localizion Directory
6. Go To XCode > Right Mouse Click on Resources > Add > Existing File ...
7. Select the localized Default.png in the Localizion Directory
8. Don't forget to mark "Copy items into destination group's folder...."  > Add
9. Repeat it with every localized Default.png

I think the trick is to delete the file you have a problem with, clean all and then add it again. If you don't have any localization there is no need to create a specific folder.

Give it a try, worked for me.

Comment: Just copied the english image to en.lproj, and Finder shows it there. When I add the file in XCode, it shows instead in sv.lproj and not in en.lproj. Whooee, magical file systems. I love Apple.

Comment: do you have a working example ?

Answer (score 7):

I'd thought I'd add the answer for localizing Launch.xib.

1. Create `InfoPlist.strings` file. (File,New,Resource,Strings)
2. Localize it and select your languages
3. For e.g. the Spanish version, add your launch screen key and name for the Spanish version of your Launch screen

   `"UILaunchStoryboardName" = "Launch_es";`
4. Copy your existing Launch.xib to Launch_es.xib, and change the text and/or images to the Spanish translations or Spanish-named images.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. I have solved it with this:

- In the Simulator, menu "simulator iOs", option "restart content and settings".
- In Xcode, menu "Build", option "Clean All Targets"

And when I have selected the button "Build and run" it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that on a latest 4.3.3 every attempt to remove and re-add the files, and the clean all, nothing worked, but what solved everything was the remove-app-from-device-and-simulator and reinstall. Now every image and xib are translated correctly.