# Is there a way to have a different Default.png (splash image) for different languages/locales in iOS?

Tags: ios, localization, splash-screen, build-settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localization of Default.png is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421868/localization-of-default-png-is-not-working)

My splash screen has English text in it, so I would like to be able to have a different splash image when users have a different language set.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Pretty much the same way you localize all your resources.
You just need to provide a Default.png image and then enable all the languages you're interested in. The result is that you'll get a copy of the image for each language into the respective folders. Then edit (or overwrite) each image as you need. I have tested it right now and it works fine (on iOS 5 but I believe is the same for older versions). Here is a screenshot for easy reference:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Regarding any doubts about whether or not this is a good practice, this is straight from [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12):

> In addition to including the launch images at the top level of your
>   bundle, you can also include localized versions of your launch images
>   in your app’s language-specific project subdirectories. For more
>   information on localizing resources in your app, see Table 6-2.

Comment: @Alladinian - a true scholar and gentleman.

Comment: You are one awesome dude. I was wrapping my head around how the heck I am going to do this, never knew it was so simple. Thank you!

Comment: Does this work for iPhone 5, 6?

Comment: Thanks this is still working for me but i am facing once issue. When i switch Device Language  after installing app splash didn't localize as per language. I mean this is just working for fresh app install. can you please help me how can i fix this ?

Comment: @ivarun i'm also facing the same issue. Did you get the solution for that?

Comment: @Ramakrishna no, still did't found any solution. i have searched a lot for this issue.

Comment: is there any working example for this? I tried a lot but not working

Answer (score 0):

<strike>No.</strike>

**Edit**: *Indeed, I'm dumbfounded. Like nevan-king I'm going to leave my answer nevertheless, since I still think that's the way it is intended to be done by the iOS guidelines (and my personal opinion about localizing whole images in order to localize its text...).*

A splash screen is not intended to provide information. Splash screens are only shown for like a second or so, so it would be unfeasible to show text anyway.

Common practice for what you want to do is to use your image *without text* as splashscreen, and after that show a custom view with your image and localized text for a few seconds.
That way it will seem like you had a localized splash screen (and the text appears shortly after the image, which is fine).

However, keep in mind that the idea of iOS apps is fast responsiveness, so only show a "startup screen" if you must (for marketing reasons or whatever).

Read this for further information: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5

Answer (score -1):

<strike>There's no way to do this. Instead, make a Default.png with no text.</strike>

**Edit:** I stand corrected. Just tried Alladinian's method and it worked. I'll leave my answer, as it's a useful technique to know.

You can do this pretty easily in Photoshop by selecting a square, then copying it and pasting it over the text. Use Marquee to select a square of your graphic (say an empty part of a navigation bar). Then hit "v" for the move tool. Use cmd-opt and move the square a little to the left, then cmd-opt-shift so that it doesn't move up or down. Move the square over the text and let go of the mouse button. Repeat as necessary.

If you want to see how Apple handles multi-language splash screens, open Maps or Mail. They have a Default screen with no text, then the text appears (in whatever language) when the app has loaded.