# Localization of icon and launch screen in iPhone iOS 8

Tags: xcode, ios8, icons, launch

Have any where a where have Localization of icon and Launch screen in iPhone? If Yes.

I read and read and read but i didn't find a example to do this.

Example XCode Please :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Icons and launch screens can't be localized, even with the new kind of launch screens that are based on storyboards instead of images

http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/

Comment: okay i will test this later but this can not working for app icon or?

Comment: Read my answer again, there is no way to localize icon and launch screens

Comment: "there is no way to localize icon and launch screens" 

This isn't entirely true. We are localizing our launch images using *.lproj approach. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Psylocke could you please explain the exact way you are able to do the trick? I've tried several ways localizing storyboard but nothing worked for me. It would be great to post all the steps here as an answer, thanks!

Comment: It CAN be localized. Check answer by Matt H in this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421868/localization-of-default-png-is-not-working

Comment: launch screens can be localized if you use "launch screen.xib"

Answer (score 0):

you can click the picture on the left of xcode,and on the right side of xcode,click localizable to localize the image,and you will notice that there are folders like en.lproj,in the folder ,change the picture with the english ones.

Answer (score 0):

Localizing Launch Screen with the help of Multiple LaunchScreen Storybaords and Plist.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45436837/1609259

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode**
Create InfoPlist.strings file and localise. ie Name it as a the country name + version

** App Store Connect & Developer Programme** n.b. you can see which icon performs best with App Store Connect (ASC) when you're app (hopefully) launches you can run A/B/C testing to see which one performs best and use that one in conjunction with localisation data offered by ASC

Hope this has helped!