# localized launchScreen.storyboard in XCode 8 are not responding to device language change

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, launch-screen

I'm trying to have the launchScreen.storyboard to change according to the language of the device.

I made storyboards with each one having a different background color for `UIImageView` at the top see sample...

[image: sampleStoryBoard]

these storyboards are localized versions of the storyboard, so each one would be chosen according to the language of the device

[image: storyboards]

the problem is :- 
it always shows the english version for example when I switch the language of the iPhone's Simulator to Arabic, how can I make each one show up for the language it's localized for?

[image]

Comment: I am curios how you are able to add different language version of LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Comment: @manismku: it's localizable like any file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, you won't be able to achieve this. Launch screens are static and it's content is not a subject to localization.

Refering to the Apple [human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/)

> **Avoid including text on your launch screen.** Because launch screens are static, any displayed text won’t be localized.

This piece of storyboard was intended to save you from creating a separate launch image for each screen resolution. iOS doesn't translate launch screen storyboards <del>as it didn't give you a way to provide launch image for each of the supported languages</del>.

However, you can find some workaround in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45436837/1692080).

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, have you set support for those languages in Project settings(under Localizations) ?

Comment: please have a look at the third image I added, yes, they are enabled.

Comment: 'Your Answer' is not a place for questions. That's what comments are for.