# Issue while trying to Localise LaunchScreen.storyboard for supporting languages using xcode 8.3.3 in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I have created different Localized versions of LaunchScreen.storyboard using Localization option available in the File Inspector.

I have added customised content in each of the storyboard (Images, Labels). When I change the Region, the LaunchScreen is still in English. Is there anything else that one has to accomplish to localize the launch screen?.

I have done some R&D on it and got to know that localization is not possible for LaunchScreen files. They are ignored. Am I missing something? Please provide your input. If yes then how to proceed.

Comment: Improved language and formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, weird but true. I just came across the same problem and it looks like usual localization won't work. The solution I ended up with was localizing Info.plist string to point different custom LaunchScreen storyboards. So, create a different storyboard for each language you want, create an InfoPlist.strings file to localise the info.plist and in each localised string file point:

```
"UILaunchStoryboardName" = "YourCustomisedStoryboardName"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering the query. Could you please explain this in more detail, creating InfoPlist.strings file to localise the info.plist

Comment: You can find an already explained one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736915/4778665

Comment: And another explaining the whole process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45436837/4778665